# How to fetch Photos album title & count in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, photos

No matter what I look for, there is no answer to my question.

I am building the iOS standard photos app.

Imagine when you turned on the Photos app.

The album title and the number of images in the album are displayed. (Like the picture)[image]

If there is no picture such as a panorama or selfie, the album title does not appear. (Excluding recently deleted)

I want to know the album title and the number of pictures that I can know when I run the photo app like this. How do I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Photos` framework  with `fetchAssetCollections`

Don't forget to adda `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` Key in your `info.plist`

```
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let albumsPhoto:PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection> = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .albumRegular, options: nil)

        albumsPhoto.enumerateObjects({(collection, index, object) in
            let photoInAlbum = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection, options: nil)
                print(photoInAlbum.count)
                print(collection.localizedTitle)

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: seems cannot find the `Recent` album